# How to load MPI modules as user in Fedora 24 using fish shell

Tags: mpi, fedora, fish

I am cannot figure out how to load MPI modules a user in Fedora.

I am using fish shell and I dont know if there will be any issues with loading a module compared to bash shell

How I am trying to load MPI modules is

```
lumx@localhost ~> sudo module load mpi
[sudo] password for lumx: 
sudo: module: command not found
lumx@localhost ~>
```

Also is there a way to load them during start up so i wont have to worry about loading modules again.

Comment: You should probably remove the "fish" label as your login shell is not relevant. The only shell specific aspect of your question is setting $PATH appropriately so that commands like `sudo` and `module` can be found.

Comment: I can load MPI modue when i use root but.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.

I just added */usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/* to my user paths. I don't know if this is the right solution instead of loading modules.

```
set -U fish_user_paths /usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/ $fish_user_paths
```

Comment: You can open the modulefile with a text editor to see how it modifies your environment. If I remember correctly, it sets both `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables. Since `mpicc` already makes sure it links properly with its own library, probably that solution is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora distributes few MPI distributions: OpenMPI and MPICH at least.
If you just install the packages, your environment is not properly set so that you can directly use the software.
However, there is one package for each distribution, which loads the required module that sets up your environment properly. For the case of MPICH is `mpich-autoload`.

On the other side, `module` command is neither a binary nor a script file, so `$PATH` value should not affect. It does not require admin rights, so you can use it in user mode directly.

Finally, I recommend you to check which modules are available in your system by running

```
$ module avail
```

Comment: Its a problem with fish shell that i didnt know. module wont work on fish shell.